# Как вывести одну определенную группу полей со всеми полями сразу? (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, веб-программирование, wordpress-плагины

Создана группа полей Real estate, необходимо вывести на главной все поля (даже те, которые не заполнены).

[image: Группа полей Real estate]

В данный момент не выводится ни одно поле: 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Получаете данные из репитера через get_field(), затем в цикле обрабатываете уже каждый елемент цикла:

```
$repeater = get_field( 'your-repeater-name' );
foreach( $repeater as $item ) {
    echo $item['your-repeater-item-field'];
}
```

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, куда это нужно писать(
В какой файл это вписывать?
Пробовала echo тестировать какие файлы за что отвечают и ничего не получилось

Comment: Читайте про иерархию шаблонов WordPress

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, подсказать в какой файл это нужно вписывать, не работает через functions.php